# Level Lowering obstructions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, discriminant

For the generalized Fermat equation:

$a^p + b^q = c^r$

with $p,q,r\ge3$ and $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$

one can construct the Frey Curve:

$y^2=x(x-a^p)(x+b^q)$

which is semi-stable for those primes $m$ that
divide the discriminant and do not divide $c_4$:

$m \mid \Delta$ and $m \nmid c_4$

where

$\Delta=16a^{2p}b^{2q}c^{2r}$ and $c_4=16(c^{2r}+a^pb^q)$.

The conductor is:

$N=2abc$

Now we are interested in the obstructions arising by level lowering $N$ to $N_m$.

For example, let $m\mid r$ and $m\mid q$.

Then, $N_m=2a$ is an obstruction for all $a$ that have a newform at level $N_m$ if there is no further way to eliminate that newform. Interestingly, $a$ can include in its prime factorization any primes except the ones in $b$ or $c$ or any other primes outside of $a$'s factorization. That is a lot of possible newforms to eliminate!

So, the question is what approach to eliminating the obstruction $N_m=2a$ in this example can be taken?